Why are these two methods for calculating combinations yielding different results?
I am trying to solve a problem involving combinations and a standard deck of cards, but I am encountering a discrepancy between two methods. Here's the setup:
We have a standard deck of $52$ cards. I want to calculate the number of ways to draw $8$ cards such that at least one card has a value greater than $8$ (values greater than $8$ include $9, 10$, J, Q, K, A).
Method 1:
First, I calculate the number of ways to draw 4 cards with at least one card having a value greater than 8. This is: $\binom{52}{4}$ - $\binom{32}{4}$.
After drawing these $4$ cards, $48$ cards remain in the deck. Now, I draw another $4$ cards (with no restrictions), which can be done in: $\binom{48}{4}$
The total number of ways using this method is: $x = [\binom{52}{4} - \binom{32}{4}] * \binom{48}{4} = 45680573700$
Method 2:
Alternatively, I can directly calculate the total number of ways to draw 8 cards such that at least one card has a value greater than 8. This is: $y = \binom{52}{8} - \binom{32}{8} = 742019850$
Issue:
The results of the two methods are not equal, i.e., $x ≠ y$. This seems counterintuitive since both methods should count the same situation: drawing $8$ cards with at least one card having a value greater than $8$.
My Question:
Why are these two methods yielding different results? Is there an error in my reasoning or calculations? How can this discrepancy be explained?

Please use MathJax.

Forget about the greater-than-$8$ thing for a moment. Just count the ways to draw eight cards. If you count them as $52C4 \times 48C4$ you are not just counting groups of eight cards; you are counting how many ways to get eight cards and then divide them into two groups of four identified as Group A and Group B. The dividing into Group A and Group B multiplies the number of combinations greatly.

Total number of drawing 8 cards in 52 is 752538150 ; so if you add constraints, you should obtain less than this number ; it is always necessary to validate by some simple checks. And when the questions contains 'At least', it is often more simple to consider the opposite ; what is the number of ways to draw 8 cards, so none of them is greater than 8. It is more or less what you do in your 2nd method, but the number 32 that you use seems wrong.
